# Unity object not rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate an object within certain boundaries, but the object does not rotate.

```
public class shincon : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb2;
    float shinspeed = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2 = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float Posax = Input.GetAxis("leftshin");
        if (Posax != 0)
        {
            Vector3 move = new Vector3(shinspeed * Posax * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Vector3 euler = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            float clampx = Mathf.Clamp(move.x + euler.x, 0, 160);
            Vector3 ready = new Vector3(clampx - euler.x, 0, 0);
            Quaternion rmove = Quaternion.Euler(ready);

            rb2.MoveRotation(rb2.rotation * rmove);
        }
    }
}
```

No syntax errors, but it will not rotate.

Comment: I am almost certain that `rb2.MoveRotation(rb2.rotation * rmove);` is not what you want here. `rmove` represents the amount you want to rotate already (and so multiplying it by the current rotation is improper). You should probably also use `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: @Draco18s Nope both is actually okey... Quaternions are added by multiplying them (see [* operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html)). Unity recommends to use `Time.deltaTime` also in `FixedUpdate` (see [Time fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)). And [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) doesn't expect an amount of rotation but the final target rotation.

Comment: But it would probably help to Debug your rotation calculation step by step .. currently I'm still trying to understand what it is supposed to do. Especially the line `transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;` .. why? And than getting it's Euler angles ... Anyway they will be `0,0,0`

Comment: @derHugo thanks! the Quaternion.identity was the problem. It was from earlier code and I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

The next

```
Vector3 euler = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
```

will always return `0,0,0`.

And further

```
Quaternion rmove = Quaternion.Euler(ready);
```

Results in `Quaternion.Identity` so finally

```
rb2.MoveRotation(rb2.rotation * rmove);
```

always results in `Quaternion.Identity` as well so the object will never be rotated.

---

Remove the line

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```